# Dialog closes after action

Tags: jsf, primefaces, modal-dialog

Whenever I perform an action in the modal dialog it closes but the action is performed because when I open the dialog again method was executed. What's wrong in my code that keeps the dialog closing after action?

mantenimientoItems.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions">

    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

        <h:form id="MantForm">
            <h:panelGrid columns="7">
                ...
                <p:inputText id="idClas"
                    value="#{MantenimientoItemsBean.itemsFiltrosVO.clasTitulo}"
                    update=":dialog3" onclick="busClas.show(); return false;">

                    <p:ajax event="click"
                    listener="#{MantenimientoItemsBean.ValidarTipoBuscador0}"/>
                </p:inputText>
                ...
        </h:form>

        <p:dialog id="dialog3" appendToBody="true" modal="true"
            widgetVar="busClas" dynamic="true" width="1400" height="850">
            <ui:include src="buscadorClasificador.xhtml" />
        </p:dialog>
    </h:body>
</ui:composition>
```

buscadorClasificador.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </h:head>

    <h:body>

        <h:form id="BClasForm">
            ...
            <tr>
                <td>
                      <p:commandButton value="Buscar" ajax="false"
                      action="#{MantenimientoItemsBean.BuscarClasificador()}"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            ...
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</ui:composition>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set the attribute `ajax="false"` on a command button, it will submit its enclosing form causing the dialog to close. If you don't won't this, you have two options, either remove the `ajax="false"` in which case the form is not submitted, or add an attribute `type="button"` which renders the `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"`, thus again avoid form submit.

Comment: u mean this?<button type="button" value="Buscar" onclick="#{MantenimientoItemsBean.BuscarClasificador()}">Buscar</button>

Comment: well, something like this  <p:commandButton value="Buscar" ajax="false" action="#MantenimientoItemsBean.BuscarClasificador()}" type="button"/> or removing ajax so  <p:commandButton value="Buscar" action="#{MantenimientoItemsBean.BuscarClasificador()}"/>